# Adding value to object adds value to all objects of the same type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pgzero

I am working with pygame libary. I have Actor classes (for game objects) and ActorContext classes (for game object lists):

```
class ActorContext:
    list = []
    alpha_range = 255
    time_diff = 0
    alpha_diff = 0

    def add(self, obj: Actor):
        self.list.append(obj)
```

In my main app I define objects:

```
enemy_context = ActorContext()
bullet_context = ActorContext()
dummy_context = ActorContext()
```

Later, in a loop, I create and add objects to those contexts:

```
            if event.key == pg.K_e:
                e = Enemy(img_src=enemy)
                e.rand_change()
                e.rand_pos()
                enemy_context.add(e)
            if event.key == pg.K_r:
                if len(enemy_list) > 0:
                    enemy_context.remove(1)
```

The problem is that when I call `enemy_context.add(e)`, the same value is added in *all* lists of objects: enemy_context, bullet_context and dummy_context

Edit: Resolved

Comment: Do the initialization in `__init__`, not at the class level.

Comment: There's just one `list` attribute, shared by all the instances.

Comment: @tobias, how do you mean?  initialization of context? I am running this in a loop, I cannot create new context each time I need to add new object...

Comment: @Barmar what should I do in this case? I also tried creating multiple sub-classes for context, but the result is still the same. Could I somehow create a copy of existing object with a different reference?

Comment: [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is not [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news). You have to use the [tag:pgzero] tag instead of the [tag:pygame] tag.

Answer (score 2):

Per-instance attributes should be initialized in the `__init__` method, not as class attributes.

```
class ActorContext:
    alpha_range = 255
    time_diff = 0
    alpha_diff = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def add(self, obj: Actor):
        self.list.append(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust your class this way:

```
class ActorContext:
    alpha_range = 255
    time_diff = 0
    alpha_diff = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def add(self, obj: Actor):
        self.list.append(obj)
```

This makes sure the `list` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute. It will now be separate for all instances of `ActorContext`.

The `__init__(self)` function is what's called a `constructor` - a special function called whenever you create an instance of related object, like `ActorContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your class ActorContext like this :

```
class ActorContext:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.alpha_range = 255
        self.time_diff = 0
        self.alpha_diff = 0

    def add(self, obj: Actor):
        self.list.append(obj)
```

Does it worked ?